# A better proof for $\mathbf{III}-2H\mathbf{II}+K\mathbf{I}=0$

Tags: differential-geometry

From [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalForms.html) , the equation 7 gives 
 $$\mathbf{III}-2H\mathbf{II}+K\mathbf{I}=0$$
where $\mathbf{III},\mathbf{II},\mathbf{I}$ are third, second and first fundamental forms respectively. $H$ is the mean curvature and $K$ is the Gauss curvature. I can only tackle this provlem when I use $\mathbf{III}=(d\mathbf{n},d\mathbf{n}),\mathbf{II}=(d\mathbf{r},d\mathbf{n})$,express it in $\mathbf{r}_u,\mathbf{r}_v$ and then compute the coefficient. The computation is a bit too ugly for this elegant equation. So I wonder if there is other elegant method in solving this problem? Is there geometric interpretation for this identity? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it so happens, I read a nice proof of this fact just two days ago.

Paraphrasing Barrett O'Neill's "[Elementary Differential Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120887355)":

> (a) Show that the [characteristic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition) of the [shape operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Shape_operator) is
> $$\lambda^2 - 2H \lambda + K.$$
>
> (b) The [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) says that every linear operator satisfies its characteristic polynomial.  Use this fact to prove that
> $$\text{III} - 2H\text{II} + K\text{I} = 0.$$